# Where can I get the hyper-parameters of the best model built with SageMaker Autopilot

Tags: boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS SageMaker's auto-pilot for a research project, and I need to report the hyper-parameters that are found for the best model.

I am using boto3 to setup AWS auto-pilot. Although I can see the hyper-parameters for the best model when I train it with the Console, when I do it with boto3 I can't find them.

Thank you for your help.